# Openlayers DEM Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF (COG)

Tags: openlayers

I am currently looking for a solution to load a Digital Elevation Model as Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF (COG) into Openlayers and do the color rendering of the elevation values in the code.
So the COG should keep the real elevation values and NOT have them as RGB values (https://openlayers.org/en/main/examples/sea-level.html)...

Thank you very much I hope it is understandable what I have in mind ...

Comment: It makes no difference whether the elevation comes from a single band or is calculated from 3 bands, it can still be interpolated and styled in the same way using WebGL - in this case the color ramp simply alternates between two colors at 50 meter intervals https://codesandbox.io/s/sea-level-forked-vm303?file=/main.js

Comment: I tried to get it working... but I failed without an guess why...

I have included my COG as source, it is also loaded in the network tab of the browser, but I get nothing displayed...

I know the display of COGs does not work in CodeSandBox, but for better understanding what I have done so far:

https://codesandbox.io/s/webgl-sea-level-forked-1thd4?file=/main.js

Comment: It is loading here https://codesandbox.io/s/webgl-sea-level-forked-jjf9m?file=/main.js but  the data appears to be all 0 in bands 1 to 3 and all 1 in band 4 (i.e. RGBA black)